# Cloning to create separate "same-langugage" sites for different countries

Tags: sitecore

I would like to use the cloning feature of Sitecore to create sites with similar content to different countries. Mostly, it would be useful if changes to master site (Russian) would be automatically reflected on the sub-sites.

- The first problem I have is that I seem to get language versions of all the items (German, English), not just Russian, when I create the clone
- The second problem is that the clone does not have items in the targets I want, e.g. Belorussian, so do I have to create it manually?

This seems like the kind of situation where cloning would be useful, but I am wondering if Sitecore architecture prevents me from actually using it?

Comment: Do you want mixed-form of content sharing among the country-specific sites, i.e. example: Logo and Slogan is common in all the sites and Page Title, Banner, meta, and images are different in each sites ?

Answer (score 2):

We have the same architecture you described for almost every of our sites. We have a "Master"-site with all overall content. This site has no `<site>`-configuration. For every country site we create a clone of this content tree and add a corresponding `<site>`-configuration. Of course we add there some country-specific content:

```
Master
- Home
  - Sitemap
  - Error
  - ...

Germany [Clone]
- Home [Clone]
  - Sitemap [Clone]
  - Error [Clone]
  - Our Office
  - ...

USA [Clone]
- Home [Clone]
  - Sitemap [Clone]
  - Error [Clone]
  - Differences
  - ...
```

This works fine, but has two drawbacks (as you also mentioned):

- The items in the master have to have a version in each language available in any of the country sites (so yes, the author may have to create the language version in the master-site and clone the item afterwards)
- The clones then have a version in each language, also if the language is not used in the country site

For the second point we've added a new parameter to the `<site>`-configurion called "availableLanguages". If the user requested i.e. an item in the "Russian"-language on "USA" (which is not available), we show a 404 error to the user. We make this possible by using the [Sitecore Error Manager](https://github.com/unic/SitecoreErrorManager) module, which also covers this parameter.

As said before we use this in almost every website we have and it works very well. It's also easy to understand for the authors.

Comment: Also, remember that you need to take care of any links pointing between items in the master tree. When an item is cloned, any links will still point to the master-item.